# Clockwise direction for RadarChart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using a D3.js RadarChart based on this example:
https://github.com/alangrafu/radar-chart-d3

My problem is that the Radar Chart displays the data sets in counterclockwise direction, but I would like to have them in clockwise direction.

I know that I could just reverse the array but I think there must be a better solution. Reversing the array also has the side-effect that now the last item would be at top-middle so it would not be done with simply reversing it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your definition of "better" is here; reversing the array is certainly easier. If you don't want to do that, you need to modify the source code. In particular, you would need to replace line 33

```
return range * (1 - factor * func(i * cfg.radians / total));
```

with

```
return range * (1 - factor * func((total - i) * cfg.radians / total));
```

as far as I can see.

Comment: I just edited my question to explain another problem concerning reversing of the array. Since I needed to edit the source anyway, I did as you suggested and it works perfectly. Thanks for your help!